# C# Lambda Expression for Unique Record for string in list of List

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have Class

```
public class ABCImport
{
  List<string> SegmentationList;

}
```

Now I have List of ABCImport.

```
var ABCImportList=New List<ABCImport>();
```

I need unique strings from SegmentationList from ABCImportList list without empty string .lets say ABCImportList have 50 record of ABCImport and each ABCImport import have SegmentationList which can be duplicate in each ABCImport .So I need unique string from all segmentation list.

This is what I have so far:

```
ABCImportList
    .Where(
        x => x.SegmentationList
            .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    )
    .Distinct()
    .ToList()
```

Comment: Without what? You've got a collection of `ABCImports` - do you want one flattened distinct list of segmentations? (Sounds like `ABCImportList.SelectMany(x => x.SegmentationList).Distinct()` would do that...

Comment: I am trying to get unique strings like bleow  ABCImportList.Where(x=>x.SegmentationList.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))).Distinct().ToList()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `SelectMany()` method which allows you to specify a collection to get all of this collection into a single result. In your case, the values of `SegmentationList` property, for sample:

```
var segmentationList = ABCImportList.SelectMany(x => x.SegmentationList.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) 
                                                                                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .ToList();
```